# How can we push to various pages without adding context in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What I am aiming for is that I have created around 5 stateful screens that are supposed to be navigated on button press. Now all the five buttons are same so I am using a for loop to assign those widgets and then add them to Column Widget list as shown below:

```
for(int i=0;i<ButtonTexts.length;i++)
      {
        NavigatorS.add(Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 40,
          child: RaisedButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(NavigatorRadius),
                side: BorderSide(color: NavigatorBorderColour)),
                onPressed: (context)=>functionCalls[i],
                color: NavigatorBarColour,
                textColor: NavigatorTextColour,
            child: Text(ButtonTexts[i],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          ),
        ));
      }
```

Now the issue is that I have created a list of functions as shown below:

```dart
List functionCalls =[buildContext(context),buildContext2(context),buildContext3(context),buildContext4(context),buildContext5(context)];
```

But these functions need context to navigate to a different screen as the functions are defined as follows:

```
void buildContext(context)
{Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BirthdayCard()),);
}
```

Someone please help me with this, also I can't use route pages as I am operating on classes, my each screen dart file is nothing but a class of stateful widget. What I want is to avoid repetative coding and pass function definitions in the onpressed option.

Comment: When you are calling screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get the exact problem that you are facing, anyway check this

```
void buildContext(context,screen)
 { 
  Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => screen),);
 }

Widget getButton(onPressed) {
  return RaisedButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(NavigatorRadius),
            side: BorderSide(color: NavigatorBorderColour)),
            onPressed: onPressed,
            color: NavigatorBarColour,
            textColor: NavigatorTextColour,
        child: Text(ButtonTexts[i],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
      ),
}
```

And in your code, you can call this,based on the conditions

```
 getButton((){
   buildContext(context,BirthdayCard());
   }
 );
```

Comment: Basically I have 5 button widgets which have only the difference of text and onPressed functionality. What I want is to loop through and append 5 Widgets into a widget list and only alter their Text properties and onpressed functionality (Navigation to 5 different pages). I wanted to know a way to create a list of functions and then call them in my loop one by one which navigates to different pages.

Comment: It's not allowing me to pass the context actually. Currently, instead of looping, I used copy paste code 5 times to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you checked this, onPressed:functionCalls[i] and List functionCalls =[buildContext,buildContext2,buildContext3,buildContext4,buildContext5];